# Firewall throughput and LAN Speed

Tags: firewall, performance, local-area-network

A quick question, I'm considering to buy a firewall which offers throughput up to 450 Mbps and has fast Ethernet ports, my understanding is that the firewall limits the internet speed but not LAN speed which is operating at 1 Gbps, am I right?

**[ISP Router] <> [Firewall] <> [Switch] <> Clients**

Should we buy another router and put between **[Firewall]** and **[Switch]** to improve LAN speed?

**[ISP Router] <> [Firewall] <> [Router] <> [Switch] <> Clients**

Only firewall has fast ethernet port, all other appliances has gigabit ethernet ports.

Will appreciate your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my understanding is that the firewall limits the internet speed but
> not LAN speed which is operating at 1 Gbps, am I right?

Yes, all it limits is what goes through it, it won't for instance slow down client to client/server traffic over that switch.

If you're either using a single vlan or the switch does any L3 routing then you don't need another router.

Comment: [ISP Router] <> [Firewall] <> [Switch] <> Clients so in this configuration. where the router is giving IP addresses (router has DHCP) to clients, the firewall is between the router and the switch will it slow down the LAN speed?

Comment: But handing out IP's via DHCP is very quick and rare traffic so in itself it won't be an issue - does your switch deal with multiple vlans or is it one big flat network?

Comment: At the moment a flat network, but thinking of creating two vLANs, vLAN10 will have access to internet, vLAN20 will not have access to internet, and I guess this can be done via a managed switch, am I right?

The main purpose of firewall is to restrict internet / outbound traffic to few websites / IP addresses by creating a whitelist, closing all ports except 80/443 for inbound traffic and allow inbound traffic from a few specific IP addresses, not sure what firewall should we purchase?

Comment: Yes that's right, you'll need either a router and managed switch or just a managed switch that can do your routing for you (called a Layer-3 Switch typically). Sounds like you're on your way to be honest, we get some real idiots come here but your first post was just fine, please come again :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a web programmer with very little knowledge of network admin / design, thanks for your help